# How to make a dynamic grid of EditText

Tags: android-layout

I want to create Dynamic grid of edittext but it gives me an IllegalStateException:

> The specific child already has a prent, You must call `removeView()`
>   on child parent first.

Here is my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < no_of_rows; x++)
{
    ll = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setOrientation(0);

    for(int y = 0; y < no_of_columns; y++){
        LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
        this.edittext2.add(new EditText(this.getApplicationContext()));
        this.edittext2.get(y).setId(y);
        this.edittext2.get(y).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                    ,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.edittext2.get(y).setMaxLines(1);
        this.edittext2.get(y).setText("Something");
        ll.addView(this.edittext2.get(y));
    }
    tlayout.addView(ll);
}
```